# Android Bitmap scale using BitmapFactory options

Tags: android

I have tried to scale bitmap using bitmap factory options inScaled, inDensity, inTargetDensity. For example, If I have bitmap size of 960 X 600, I want to scale up to size of 1440 X 900. So I have set denisty as 2 and targetdensity as 3.
Issue is returned bitmap size is same as the one returned in first decodeByteArray function. Bitmap is not scaled as per the denisty factor. What is the issue in my code?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, size, options);
int bmpWidth = options.outWidth;
int bmpHeight = options.outHeight;

options.inDensity = 2;
options.inTargetDensity = 3;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
options.inScaled = true;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, size, options);
int scaledBmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
int scaledBmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that not all decodeXXX methods respect density options. You can try to wrap the array with ByteArrayInputStream and use decodeStream method.

See eg. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7538.

Answer (score -1):

Set the outWidth and outHeight of the resulting bitmap.

```
options.outWidth = bmpWidth * factor;
options.outHeight = bmpHeight * factor;
```

Comment: `options.out*` variables/properties are set when `options.inJustDecodeBounds` is set to `true`. That way you can get width, height and mime type of the image without actually loading it into memory.